# Prolog concatenate atoms

Tags: prolog, concatenation

I want to write prolog that can do what this is doing:

```
atomic_list_concat([X,'(', Y,')'],Z).
```

where, in my code X is an atom localization, Y is what user answer after a read, so it's what he input (for example blabla).

The Z would be: `localization(blabla)`

The result of atomic_list_concat is `'localization(blabla)'`.

I would like the answer to have no quotation marks in it.

Please, help me

Comment: I'm using YAP 6.2.2, and i need the result without quotation mark....

Comment: I don't have YAP installed so will not be answering this and can not give more specific help.

Answer (score 1):

To create a compound term, you shoud use

```
Z =.. [X, Y]
```

instead of

```
atomic_list_concat([X, '(', Y, ')'], Z)
```

For example:

```
?- X = localization, Y= blabla, Z =.. [X, Y].
X = localization, 
Y = blabla, 
Z = localization(blabla).
```